# App Started Crashing When Adding New Document to Firestore (Continued Crashing Even After Document Was Deleted)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

This is my relevant struct:

```
struct MealPlan {
    
    var docID:String?
    var title:String?
    var ingredientsProduce:[String]?
    var ingredientsProtein:[String]?
    var ingredientsSpices:[String]?
    var ingredientsOther:[String]?
    var isStarred:Bool?
    
}
```

And this is my model:

```
class MealPlanModel {
    
    var delegate:MealPlanProtocol?
    var listener:ListenerRegistration?
    
    func getMealPlans(_ starredOnly:Bool = false) {
        
        // Detach any listener
        listener?.remove()
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        var query:Query = db.collection("mealPlans")
        
        // If filtering for starred Meal Plans, update the query
        if starredOnly {
            query = query.whereField("isStarred", isEqualTo: true)
        }
        
        self.listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                
                var mealPlans = [MealPlan]()
                
                // Parse documents into mealPlans
                for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let m = MealPlan(docID: doc["docID"] as! String, title: doc["title"] as! String, ingredientsProduce: doc["ingredientsProduce"] as! [String], ingredientsProtein: doc["ingredientsProtein"] as! [String], ingredientsSpices: doc["ingredientsSpices"] as! [String], ingredientsOther: doc["ingredientsOther"] as! [String], isStarred: doc["isStarred"] as! Bool)
                    
                    mealPlans.append(m)
                    
                }
                
                // Call the delegate and pass back the notes in the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: mealPlans)
                }
                
                
            }
            
        })
```

This is what I can't figure out:

1. My project was building fine with this code
2. Then I added a new document in Firestore with the same keys
3. App started crashing
4. I deleted that document from Firestore (so going back to where I was at (1) when it worked) and the project continued to crash

The error I'm getting is: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The error is marked at `ingredientsProduce: doc["ingredientsProduce"] as! [String]` from my code above.

I couldn't find any typos and the keys all have values in Firestore. Also, everything was working fine before I added/deleted the new document, so it seems like nothing has changed since it last worked. I cleared my build folder and quit/reopened Xcode as well.

Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Is `"ingredientsProduce"` an array of some kind? If not what does its actual structure look like in Firestore - can you include a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are force unwrapping an optional value hence your app is crashing when it turns out to be nil.

```
doc["ingredientsProduce"] as! [String] // as! means force cast it to array of strings in your example
```

If the value of ingredientsProduce is an optional you can't force unwrap it and expect it not to crash when it's nil.

Example of safe unwrapping

```
if let myValues = doc["ingredientsProduce"] as? [String] {
    // safe to use myValues
    _ = myValues.map { print($0) }
}
```

Comment: [String] is an array of strings, not a dictionary which would be [String: Any] for example.

Comment: Thank you! I changed everything to safely unwrap instead and it worked. Much appreciated!